# Differential equations: solving separable equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the separable equation $y' = (x-8)e^{-2y}$ satisfying the initial condition $y(8)=\ln(8)$. I can not figure this out I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show your work? Regards

Comment: I took the e^-2y and divided it to the other side, then took the integrals of both sides with respect to x.  Then I had e^-2y=x^2-16x+c

Comment: You were doing great! Use the IC and solve for C. Take logs of both sides and solve for $y$. You got this!

Comment: Remember that the right-hand side is $ \ \frac{x-8}{e^{2y}} \ , $ so when you move the factor to the left-hand side, that will become $ \ e^{+2y} \ dy \ . $

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=(x-8)e^{-2y}\implies e^{2y}dy=(x-8)dx$$

Integrating either sides

$$\frac{e^{2y}}2=\frac{x^2}2-8x+C\implies e^{2y}=x^2-16x+2C$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant

Putting $x=8, y=\ln8, e^{2\ln 8}=8^2-16\cdot8+2C$

$2C-64=(e^{\ln 8})^2=8^2\implies 2C=64+64$

Comment: So c is 32 correct? once I have that what do I do. My answer box is in the form of y=

Comment: @john, $2C=64+64\implies  e^{2y}=x^2-16x+128$ as $C$ is constant

Comment: Thank you so much Figured it out!